# How to print nested lists using nested loops?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops, nested-lists

Hi i have a simplified example of my problem.

i would like to get an output of

```
1
a
b
2
c
3
d
e
f
4
g
5
h
```

I have tried different variations but can figure out the logic. My code is below. Thanks for your help in advance. I am trying to do it without using numpy or panda. I am using python3.4

```
num = ["1" , "2" ,"3" , "4" , "5" ]
let = [["a","b"],["c"],["d","e","f"],["g"],["h"]]


for x in num :
    print(x)
    for y in let :
        print(y)

zipBoth = zip(num,let)


for x,y in zipBoth :
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are trying to print the contents of two lists. This is a linear operation in time. Two loops just won't cut it - that's quadratic in time complexity. Furthermore, your second solution doesn't flatten `y`.

---

Define a helper function using `yield` and `yield from`.

```
def foo(l1, l2):
    for x, y in zip(l1, l2):
        yield x
        yield from y        

for i in foo(num, let):
     print(i)

1
a
b
2
c
3
d
e
f
4
g
5
h
```

If you want a list instead, just call `foo` with a `list` wrapper around it:

```
print(list(foo(num, let)))
['1', 'a', 'b', '2', 'c', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f', '4', 'g', '5', 'h']
```

Note that `yield from` becomes available to use from python3.3 onwards.

Comment: Thanks coldspeed I look into the use of yield.

Answer (score 1):

just `zip` the lists and flatten twice applying `itertools.chain`

```
num = ["1" , "2" ,"3" , "4" , "5" ]
let = [["a","b"],["c"],["d","e","f"],["g"],["h"]]

import itertools

result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(num,let))))
```

now `result` yields:

```
['1', 'a', 'b', '2', 'c', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f', '4', 'g', '5', 'h']
```

which you can print with:

```
print(*result,sep="\n")
```

Comment: So it looks less ugly: `flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable`, and then call `flatten` twice.

Comment: I was being sarcastic :) that said I don't understand why the _question_ has been downvoted... it's not that bad.

Comment: Thanks fabre I will look into itertools. I am yet to use that.

Answer (score 1):

```
numlet = [c for n, l in zip(num,let) for c in [n] + l]
for c in numlet:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the list `let` using `pydash`. [pydash](http://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a utility library.

Print each element from the concatenated list (`num + pydash.flatten(let)`)

```
>>> import pydash as pyd
>>> num = ["1" , "2" ,"3" , "4" , "5" ]
>>> let = [["a","b"],["c"],["d","e","f"],["g"],["h"]]
>>> for i in [str(j) for j in num + pyd.flatten(let)]:
...     print(i)
1
2
3
4
5
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
>>>
```

Comment: The lack of explanation adds to the mystery (and consequent unhelpfulness) of your answer.

Comment: Updated the explanation. I am using `pydash` utility library to flatten the elements in `let`

Answer (score 0):

this solution assumes that "num" and "let" have the same number of elements

```
num = ["1" , "2" ,"3" , "4" , "5" ]
let = [["a","b"],["c"],["d","e","f"],["g"],["h"]]

for i in range(len(num)):
    print num[i]
    print '\n'.join(let[i])
```